# In Lurie's "Higher topos theory" lemma 4.3.2.7

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

In Lurie's "[Higher topos theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608040)" lemma 4.3.2.7, I’m trying to understand “In particular, we may identify $p$-colimits of $F$ with $p$-colimits of $F_0$”:

> **Lemma 4.3.2.7**.  Suppose we are given a diagram of $\infty$-categories
> [image: \xymatrix{ \calC^{0} \ar@{^{(}->}[d] \ar[r]^{F_0} & \calD \ar[d]^{p} \ \calC \ar[r] \ar[ur]^{F} & \calD' }]
>
> as in Definition 4.3.2.2, where $p$ is a categorical fibration and $F$ is a $p$-left Kan extension of $F_0$.  Then the induced map
> $$\mathcal D_{F/} \to \mathcal D'_{p F/} \times_{\mathcal D'_{p F_0/}} \mathcal D_{F_0/}$$
> is a trivial fibration of simplicial sets.  In particular, we may identify $p$-colimits of $F$ with $p$-colimits of $F_0$.

It seems that here we have $C\rightarrow C*\mathrm{pt}$ is a homotopy pushout of right cone $C_0\rightarrow C_0*\mathrm{pt}$ via the embedding of quasi-categories $C_0\rightarrow C$, but why?

Or, is there another way to figure out “In particular, we may identify $p$-colimits of $F$ with $p$-colimits of $F_0$.”?

Comment: Another version of the second half of this statement is given in Kerodon. It's a bit more explicit: https://kerodon.net/tag/030V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer first the question about the homotopy pushout. It is in general *not* the case. Consider for instance the inclusion $\Delta^0 \to \Delta^1$. Then $\Delta^0 \star * = \Delta^1$ so that the homotopy pushout with $\Delta^1$ along $\Delta^0$ (computed as sinply the pushout, because it's along a cofibration) is just $\Lambda^2_0$, which is already a quasicategory, whereas $\Delta^1\star * = \Delta^2$, and they are not equivalent.

For the question about this comment, note that you can reformulate the statement of the lemma as : the following square is a pullback square :

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}D_{F/} @>>> D_{F_0/} \\
@VVV @VVV \\
D'_{pF/} @>>> D'_{pF_0/} \end{CD}$

Now in this kind of situation, a diagram in the top left hand corner which is $p$-initial when moved to the right was $p$-initial to begin with. This is 4.3.1.5.(4) in HTT.

This shows that a cocone under $F$ wich restricts to a $p$-colimit of $F_0$ is a $p$-colimit of $F$. See Daniel's comment below to see why there shouldn't be a converse in general.

Given a $p$-colimit of $F_0$, say $\overline{F_0}: C_0^\triangleright \to D$, by relative Kan extension, if you're also given an extension $\overline F  : C^\triangleright \to D'$ of $p\circ \overline{F_0}$, then you get a diagram $\Delta^0\to D_{F/}$ which becomes a $p$-colimit of $F_0$ under restriction, so again by the above, a $p$-colimit of $F$.

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly on "Kan extension gives you something with a map from F"? I'm unsure how to do this since we only have a relative Kan extension, so it seems non-obvious that one can lift something from $D_{F_0/}$ to $D_{F/}$ without something from $D'_{pF/}$ or similar.

Comment: @DanielGratzer : Yes, that's probably right... I went a bit too quick there. This means one probably needs to read the statement as a one-directional thing : "$p$-colimits of $F$ are $p$-colimits of $F_0$ (but not necessarily conversely)"

Comment: Yes... confusingly this is all I can establish as well. It's a bit odd because Lurie claims "iff" not only in HTT, but also in the rephrasing in Kerodon (https://kerodon.net/tag/030V) so perhaps I'm missing something obvious

Comment: @DanielGratzer : This iff is correct, because you *start* with a diagram $\overline F$, in other words you have something in $D'_{pF/}$

Comment: And you see that the Kerodon statement is less vague than the one in HTT :)

Comment: If it's not too presumptuous, I'd draw your attention to [the related question I've asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424602/question-about-the-proof-of-kerodon-tag-030v-proposition-7-3-7-1) about the proof given in Kerodon.

Comment: @DanielGratzer I tried to give it a shot, let me know if my answer is clear :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I have two more questions: 1. It seems 4.3.1.5.(4) in HTT (combined with your last paragraph) only implies that $p$-colimit of $F_0$ yields a $p$-colimit of $F$, not "This shows that a $p$-colimit of $F$ gives you a $p$-colimit of $F_0$". 2. Instead of equivalence, could we prove that $P:C_0*pt\coprod_{C_0}C\rightarrow C*pt$ is left anodyne?(In my original approach I was considering $D_{\bar{F}/}\rightarrow D_{\bar{F}P/}$). I'd appreciate it if you could elaborate more on those.

Comment: @XiaYu : you're right, I went a bit quick, I had in mind the situation where $D$ had $p$-colimits for $F_0$, where you can make that sort of "backwards" deduction. In the general case, here's how one can do it : the $p$-colimit of $F$ is a diagran $C\star \Delta^0 \to D$, which is $p$-left Kan extended from $C$, therefore from $C_0$, and therefore its restriction to $(C_0)\star \Delta^0$ is $p$-left Kan extended from $C_0$. I'll edit my answer with a clarification of that when I have the time :)

Comment: Ah I just realized I'm implicitly using 4.3.2.8. which comes right after and is deduced fron 4.3.2.7

Comment: In that case, I think you shoukd have a look at Daniel Gratzer's post, which he linked to above. It is a deduction from 4.3.2.7, because the pullback that is in 4.3.2.7 is what yields the homotopy pullbacks of mapping spaces that appear there, but it is a different kind of proof

Comment: Thanks, and I figure out that the claim in my question 2 generally not holds.

Comment: Indeed, I expect it not to hold in general. For instance, imagine you're trying to lift against $X\to *$ for some Kan complex (which is a fibration, hence a left fibration). Then in terms of homotopy types of the geometric realizations, the coproduct is something like the cofiber of $|C_0|\to |C|$ which can be essentially arbitrary, whereas $|C^\triangleright|$ is contractible. So you would be saying that any map to a Kan complex factors through a contractible space, in other words it would be contractible